# Selenium random failure

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

In Selenium, I initially had 30 tests and it passed all tests successfully. Now I have 130 tests and every time I run, it fails some random tests or if I get lucky it passes all. Does anyone have faced such instability in Selenium?

Comment: _it fails some random tests_, update the question with the complete error stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Yep, it's bad

Especially if your tests are against a public web site and run on a variety of browsers, timing will vary quite a lot, and the various web drivers have widely varying degrees of quality.  Selenium tests are just not very deterministic even in a controlled environment.  Some web driver/browser combinations are particularly failure-prone.  (In my personal experience, Safari is the worst by far, much worse than, say, IE 11.)

## What's a failure?

Our policy is to only count a failure if the test fails three times.  We run all the tests, rerun the failures, then rerun the remaining failures once more.  Then we start investigating.

## Steady improvement

If you keep a test result history (and you should!), then from time to time you can examine the tests that most often fail on first run and see if there are improvements you can make.  We have a regular flaky-test meeting where we try to improve at least one test without compromising the test's integrity.  As an example of what this can look like, here's the (Java) code we use to get Safari to be less flaky:

```
public void click(boolean useSafariWorkaround) {
    if (useSafariWorkaround && driver.isSafari()) {
        driver.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", webElement);
    }
    else {
        webElement.click();
    }
}
```

If we don't use special handling for Safari, it often fails on clicks.  But if we use this workaround *everywhere*, a lot of places fail that would otherwise work.  So we default to `false` when we call this, and change it to true only in places where Safari tends to fail.

## Wait, but not forever

Of course, you should be using implicit waits in most places, where you poll for up to 5 or 10 seconds for something on the page, and only fail if you can't find it in that amount of time.  Make sure you use the wait methods provided with Selenium (e.g. `WebDriverWait`) so you don't wait longer than you have to.  Selenium tests are slow enough without waiting a hard 5 or 10 seconds on every selector.

Answer (score 0):

Flakyness in selenium tests is pretty well known. Make sure you are using explicit waits and don't mix implicit and explicit wait in your scripts. Alternatively you can try running the tests headless and see the behaviour or preferably run the scripts in a seperate machine with browser or use a VM on your system to run the tests.